# Real-life applications of linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Robot Moe is assembling memory cards for computers. At 9:00 am, 52
cards had been assembled. At 11:00 am, a total of 98 had been made.
Assuming the production rate is linear.

> a. Find the slope of this line and explain what it means in this
>   context.

Would it reasonable to say that this equation is legitimate for this Robot?

[image]

> b. Determine how many boards Moe can assemble in an eight-
>   hour day.

[image]
Well according to my calculator it seems he started at 7 am and he can do 23 boards per hour.

> c. Find a linear equation to model the data.

It can be found in my first image

> d. Determine the approximate time Moe began working this
>   morning.

7 a.m.

Can anyone verify my answers I just want to make sure I'm on the right path?

Comment: The slope is 23, but the intercept is -155, not zero like you drew it. i.e the line should intercept the y-axes at -155 not zero.  May be you meant to post this in the math group? not Mathematica?

Comment: Yes your right I'll fix that! Thanks for the tip.